# How to generate merit list from exam results in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using  SQL Server 2008 R2. I have a table called `tstResult` in my database.

```
 AI  SubID  StudID  StudName  TotalMarks  ObtainedMarks
--------------------------------------------------------
 1  |   1  |   1  |  Jakir   |    100    |    90
 2  |   1  |   2  |  Rubel   |    100    |    75
 3  |   1  |   3  |  Ruhul   |    100    |    82
 4  |   1  |   4  |  Beauty  |    100    |    82
 5  |   1  |   5  |  Bulbul  |    100    |    96
 6  |   1  |   6  |  Ripon   |    100    |    82
 7  |   1  |   7  |  Aador   |    100    |    76
 8  |   1  |   8  |  Jibon   |    100    |    80
 9  |   1  |   9  |  Rahaat  |    100    |    82
```

Now I want a SELECT query that generate a merit list according to the Obtained Marks. In this query obtained marks "96" will be the top in the merit list and all the "82" marks will be placed one after another in the merit list. Something like this:

```
  StudID  StudName  TotalMarks  ObtainedMarks Merit List
 ----------------------------------------------------------
 |   5  |  Bulbul  |    100    |     96     |   1
 |   1  |  Jakir   |    100    |     90     |   2
 |   9  |  Rahaat  |    100    |     82     |   3
 |   3  |  Ruhul   |    100    |     82     |   3
 |   4  |  Beauty  |    100    |     82     |   3
 |   6  |  Ripon   |    100    |     82     |   3
 |   8  |  Jibon   |    100    |     80     |   4
 |   7  |  Aador   |    100    |     76     |   5
 |   2  |  Rubel   |    100    |     75     |   6
```

Comment: why 82 will get same position in merit list ?on what basis ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
;with cte as
(
select *, dense_rank() over (order by ObtainedMarks desc) as Merit_List
from tstResult
)

select * from cte order by Merit_List desc
```

you need to use [Dense_rank()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

```
select columns from tstResult order by ObtainedMarks desc
```